# matplotlib figure coordinates of plot area

Tags: matplotlib, plot, coordinates, area, figure

How do you find the location of the plot area of an axes in figure coordinates or pixel coordinates?

I'm actually trying to capture click and motion events on the x axis area below the plot.  So I'm getting an event and trying to test if it's y coordinate is below the plot area.  I would think this is simple, but I can't seem to find anything by searching.

Comment: Dale, if you post this as an answer to your question below, I'd be happy to up-vote it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOLVED - found it - wasn't easy to find - axes.bbox.bounds bounds is in pixels, same as the event.

Comment: Well that didn't work. I'm making more of a mess here so I'll just leave it.  If someone who knows how wants to edit and clean up this question go ahead.  Next time I won't edit, I'll ANSWER.